# TThread.WaitFor on multiple consecutive threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freepascal, lazarus

A thread (TThreadStarter) is created and it will in turn create a number of worker threads and must wait for them to finish before proceeding. It must work under both Linux and Windows.

The approach below seems to be a solution. But is it a good one? Would you do it differently?

1) Create and put all threads in an array, then run through the array and call Start.

2) Then simply run through the array again and call WaitFor so execution stops
for the calling thread until all threads has finished.

```
procedure TThreadStarter.Execute;
var i1:integer;
begin
  for i1:=1 to WORK_THREAD_COUNT do ThreadArray[i1].Start;
  for i1:=1 to WORK_THREAD_COUNT do ThreadArray[i1].WaitFor;

  ..Do some work

end;
```

I use Lazarus and FreePascal.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way.

Comment: On Windows it is more efficient to use one of the Win32 API functions that allow you to wait on multiple handles.

Comment: Call `WaitFor` works but may be not optimal. You have three scenarios: Best case - shortest thread first, longest thread last. Middle case - all threads consume approximately same amount of time. Worst case - longest thread first, shortest thread last. Actually, the differences are marginal. Perfect solution is to use `WaitForMultipleObjects`, as David already said.

Comment: @René, do you have a similar solution for Linux then ? If so, then you found an optimal solution. And, I doubt you would even notice a performance difference between waiting for single object in a loop and waiting for multiple objects when working with reasonable number of threads. It also doesn't matter which thread finishes as last. It can be the first one no matter what. Your loop will just break there waiting on its finish and once it's done, the rest of the threads asked in the remaining iterations will return *immediately* their `WaitFor` method calls.

Comment: @TLama It can matter. Waiting involves transition to kernel mode. 63 needless transitions (worst case) is no good. It's easy to abstract away platform variation to take advantage of the richer threading primitives available on Windows.

Comment: @TLama Thanks for confirming that the solution is viable, thats just what I needed. Will keep in mind what René and David said for future programs.

Comment: TLama: there is no nice solution for linux, other than allocating a pipe (or something else with a filehandle) and doing select on the bunch of them. The following workaround is also interesting (since at least it blocks) http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-implement-waitformultipleobjects-in-linux-908553/

Answer (score 0):

Solution for waiting on an (almost) arbitrary count of worker threads (Windows only).

Call `WaitForThreads` function from your `MainWorkerThread` (not the normal main thread) and pass in an array of all the thread handles you want to wait for.

```
interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes;

type
  THandleDynArray = array of THandle;

  TMaximum_Wait_Objects_Handles = array[0..MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS - 1] of THandle;

  EMaximum_Handles_Exceeded = class(Exception);

  TThreadWaitForThreads = class(TThread)
  strict private
    FarrHandle: TMaximum_Wait_Objects_Handles;
    FThreadWaitCount: 0..MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure AddHandle(Handle: THandle); overload;
    procedure AddHandle(HandleArray: THandleDynArray); overload;
    procedure ClearHandles;
  end;

procedure WaitForThreads(const Handles: THandleDynArray);

implementation

procedure WaitForThreads(const Handles: THandleDynArray);
var
  Wait_Result: cardinal;
  arrHandle: TMaximum_Wait_Objects_Handles;
  arrWaitThreads: array[0..MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS - 1] of TThreadWaitForThreads;
  WaitThreadsCount, i: integer;
begin
  if Length(Handles) <= 0 then
    exit;    

  if Length(Handles) > MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS then
  begin
    WaitThreadsCount := Length(Handles) div MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS;

    for i := 0 to WaitThreadsCount - 1 do
    begin
      arrWaitThreads[i] := TThreadWaitForThreads.Create(true);
      arrHandle[i] := arrWaitThreads[i].Handle;

      arrWaitThreads[i].AddHandle(Copy(Handles, MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS * i, MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS));
    end;

    try
      if Length(Handles) mod MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS > 0 then
        Move(Handles[MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS * WaitThreadsCount], arrHandle[WaitThreadsCount], (Length(Handles) - WaitThreadsCount * MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS) * SizeOf(THandle));

      for i := 0 to WaitThreadsCount - 1 do
        arrWaitThreads[i].Resume;

      repeat
        Wait_Result := WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(WaitThreadsCount + Length(Handles) - WaitThreadsCount * MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS, @arrHandle, true, 10, true);
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      until ((Wait_Result <> WAIT_TIMEOUT)
        and (Wait_Result <> WAIT_IO_COMPLETION));

    finally
      for i := 0 to WaitThreadsCount - 1 do
      begin
        arrWaitThreads[i].Terminate; // terminating all WaitThreads to be on the safe side
        arrWaitThreads[i].Free;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    repeat
      Wait_Result := WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(Length(Handles), @Handles[0], true, 10, true);
      Application.ProcessMessages;
    until ((Wait_Result <> WAIT_TIMEOUT)
      and (Wait_Result <> WAIT_IO_COMPLETION));
  end;
end;

{ TThreadWaitForThreads }

procedure TThreadWaitForThreads.AddHandle(Handle: THandle);
begin
  if FThreadWaitCount < MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS then
  begin
    FarrHandle[FThreadWaitCount] := Handle;
    Inc(FThreadWaitCount);
  end
  else
    raise EMaximum_Handles_Exceeded.Create('You can only wait for ' + IntToStr(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS) + ' Threads!');
end;

procedure TThreadWaitForThreads.AddHandle(HandleArray: THandleDynArray);
begin
  if FThreadWaitCount + Length(HandleArray) <= MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS then
  begin
    Move(HandleArray[0], FarrHandle[FThreadWaitCount], SizeOf(THandle) * Length(HandleArray));
    Inc(FThreadWaitCount, Length(HandleArray));
  end
  else
    raise EMaximum_Handles_Exceeded.Create('You want to wait for ' + IntToStr(FThreadWaitCount + Length(HandleArray)) + ' threads, but you can only wait for ' + IntToStr(MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS) + '!');
end;

procedure TThreadWaitForThreads.ClearHandles;
begin
  FThreadWaitCount := 0;
  ZeroMemory(@FarrHandle, SizeOf(FarrHandle));
end;

procedure TThreadWaitForThreads.Execute;
var
  Wait_Result: cardinal;
begin
  if FThreadWaitCount = 0 then
    exit;

  repeat
    Wait_Result := WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(FThreadWaitCount, @FarrHandle, true, 10, true);
  until ((Wait_Result <> WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    and (Wait_Result <> WAIT_IO_COMPLETION))
    or Terminated;

  ClearHandles;
end;

end.
```